# Setting up Geneva server for Windows Integrated security scenario

Tags: geneva-server

I have an Intranet website and would like to use Windows Integrated security with Geneva. I have configured the server and works fine with Username/password scenario but i would like logged on windows user to authenticate straight onto the application with appropriate claims.
I get a 401 authorization failed error when I use windows integrated security. How do I set up the Passive example site (RP) to log me straight in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer lies on this page:
[Setting up Geneva server for Windows Integrated security standard](http://blogs.southworks.net/gabrielsz/2009/06/24/geneva-server-beta-2-troubleshooting-windows-integrated-authentication/#comment-24)

& [MSDN Social link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/2ea18257-4d09-4770-b8d8-93023f8c2e8f)